# An xpath query that returns all nodes with the id attribute set

Tags: dom, attributes, xquery

I can make a query that returns a result set of nodes with their id set to a value I know.  But I can't figure out how to get a result set of all nodes that have an id explicitly set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to get a result set of all nodes that have an id explicitly set.

`*[@id]` will select all nodes with an `[id]` attribute:

The catch is that it will pick up nodes where id is present but is empty (i.e. `id=""`)

If you want to ignore nodes with empty `[id]` attributes, use: `*[@id!=""]`

Comment: The predicate `[@id]` is correct. It will select elements having an `id` attribute. Your second recommendation is verbose. This predicate `[@id!=""]` is enough, because you are asking *Is there an `id` attribute with not empty string value?*

Comment: Close, it turns out to be //*[@id][@id!=""].  Rock, thanks for the answere.

Comment: @Alejandro, your right //*[@id!=''] works just as well.  thank you both.